# Match all substrings in string except specific pattern

Tags: swift, regex

in this string: "TESTING (hello) 123 (HOW ARE YOU)"

I would like to match:

```
TESTING
123
```

Please help.. thanks!

I am only able to use `(\\\(.*?\))` to match `\(hello)` and `\(HOW ARE YOU)`, how can i match the counterpart of this strings?

Comment: So you actually have `let s = "TESTING \\(hello) 123 \\(HOW ARE YOU)"` as input, right?

Comment: Try `[^\\()]+(?=\\\()|(?<=\))[^\\()]+`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah

Comment: @Sweeper omg that works! Thank you so so so much!! :)

Comment: @maymaymaymaymay See Wiktor Stribiżew's solution. It's much faster than mine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way with ICU (the regex library used in Swift) regex to match a text chunk that is not equal to some multicharacter string. You could do it if you wanted to match any 1 or more chars other than some specific character. You can't do it if you are "negating" a whole *sequence* of chars.

You may use

```
let str = "TESTING \\(hello) 123 \\(HOW ARE YOU)"
let pattern = "\\s*\\\\\\([^()]*\\)\\s*"
let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "\0", options: .regularExpression)
print(result.components(separatedBy: "\0").filter({ $0 != ""}))
```

Output: `["TESTING", "123"]`

The idea is to match what you do not need and replace them with a null char, and then split the string with that null char.

**Pattern details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\\(` - a `\(` substring
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

The results are likely to contain empty strings, hence `.filter({ $0 != ""})` is used to filter them out.

Comment: What if i have two strings:
```a = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU"
b = "TESTING \\(hello) 123 \\(HOW ARE YOU)"```
is it possible to have a regex that matches
```"HELLO HOW ARE YOU" in a
and "TESTING", "123" in b?```

Comment: @maymaymaymaymay For your `a` string, the result is `["HELLO HOW ARE YOU"]`. For the `b` string,  I get `["TESTING", "123"]`. Just what you ask for.

Comment: @maymaymaymaymay To clear it out for you: there is no way with ICU regex to match a text chunk that is not equal to some multicharacter string. You could do it if you wanted to match any 1 or more chars other than some specific character. You can't do it if you are "negating" a whole *sequence* of chars.